# How do you make a Word add-in that runs offline?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, offlineapps, word-addins

I have successfully built an add-in for Word 15 (2016) similar to [this one](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins?product=word).

However, I would like my app to be usable even when the user is offline by using appcache, [which is possible with Word 2013](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Apps-for-Office-Enable-bdcb7a2f). However, I can't get appcache to work in Word 2016.

So I am wondering: Does appcache work in Word 2016? Is it possible to make Word 2016 add-ins that run offline? If so, how?

Comment: Traditional Office Add-ins are written as COM components (you can also use C#/.NET, C++, even VB6) which use the Office COM Automation API for performing tasks - it also means you can target Office versions going back to Office 2000 and beyond. Have you considered rewriting it to use COM instead of the new Javascript API?

Comment: Also note that "Apps for Office" are different from true Office Add-ins.

Comment: @Dai However  the COM components won't work on an ipad.